# How do I query parent details and top child record at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Not sure how I would describe this, so I think my title may be a little off. But it boils down to, "please write this query for me, I'm stuck as hell"

I have two tables (relevant parts only)

```
//MyEntity
--------
Id
Name

//MyEntLogEntries
---------------
MyEntityId
TimeStamp
Username
Content
```

I want to return a list in this form

```
Entity.Id,Name,"latest related log entry's username WITH a username not null"
```

But the log entries might have newer entries without a username. So I need the last entry with a username.

I've been getting the list of entities and querying for the latest entry separately but this gives me the dreaded N+1 queries for the report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

```
SELECT E.Id, E.Name, T.*
FROM MyEntity E
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM MyEntLogEntries L WHERE L.MyEntityId = E.Id AND Username IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) T
```

And another

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT E.Id,
       E.Name,
       L.MyEntityId,
       L.TimeStamp,
       L.Username,
       L.Content,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  E.Id ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS RN
FROM MyEntity E
LEFT JOIN MyEntLogEntries L ON L.MyEntityId = E.Id AND Username IS NOT NULL   

)
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1
```